# Regex match pattern with prefixed string

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my possible test string: `(opacity=0)`or `(opacity=50)` or `(opacity=100)`, the rules for opacity value must fall in [0, 100].

My attempt is `/opacity=([1-9][0-9]?|100)/` in `Javascript`. But it doesn't capture the 100.

Here is the [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/pB3dR3/1) for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 100 as the first alternative and move the `?` quantifier to the `[1-9]` character class:

```
opacity=(100|[1-9]?[0-9])
```

*However*, this regex [also matches](https://regex101.com/r/dF4sC0/1) `20` in `opacity=200`.

To make sure you **only match 0 up to 100**, you should add a `\b` word boundary:

```
opacity=(100|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
                         ^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG3qK9/2).

Note that `100` must be the first alternative in the group because it is a longer part than `0` or `18`, and it should be tested before any 1- or 2-digit number since the regex engine searches for matches from left to right. **However, the order of alternatives is irrelevant when using `\b`** as it requires the word boundary to appear after the number.

Comment: Excellent explanation and nice catch on the word boundary.

Comment: This is a pedantically correct answer to the question, but in the real world it would *probably* be better to just match `opacity=(\d+)` and then validate that the number is in the expected range using code; that way you have a more straightforward regex and can throw *different* errors for an out-of-range opacity value or a string that totally fails to match the format, which this approach can't distinguish. It's hard to be certain of the best approach without knowing the OP's use case, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the regex is greedy. Your first capture group with the 2 digits automatically grabs everything it can. This behaviour is called "greedy".

`opacity=([1-9][0-9]?|100)\b`

One change could be to but a at the end of the regex. `\b` tells your regex-tester that the word/number ends here.

Alternatively you could put the 100 in front of the 2 digit number

`opacity=(100|[1-9][0-9]?)\b`

That way it still works greedy ( from left to right ) and searches for your 100 first. This is exactly the behaviour you want.

Comment: The `opacity=(100|[1-9][0-9]?)` still needs the word boundary to exclude `200` though, but nice analysis.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
opacity=(100|\d{1,2})
```

[regex test](https://www.regex101.com/r/pB3dR3/3)

Comment: well this would also be true for 300 which is an invalid opacity.

Comment: Still bad; this matches `opacity=` on its own.

Comment: it would still match numbers with a leading zero.

Comment: @jvecsei, not specified in the OP.

Comment: well you can see in his question that he was trying to do this.